# Filter Values from Query that Exist in Another Query

Tags: c#, sql

I have been trying to come up with a solution to this for a while. I have a query that displays the products associated with a package. To had to do a 3-table join to get these values, which work without any issues.

I tried to create a query to show all available products not in the package. I have tried filtering these values out within my query without any any luck and have tried multiple different approaches.

This is my current query:

```
string showProdQuery = 
    @"SELECT DISTINCT ProdName FROM Products P " +
    "INNER JOIN Products_Suppliers S ON P.ProductId = S.ProductId " +
    "INNER JOIN Packages_Products_Suppliers O ON S.ProductSupplierId = O.ProductSupplierId " +
    "INNER JOIN Packages G ON G.PackageId = O.PackageId " +
    "WHERE O.PackageId NOT LIKE @PackageId AND G.PackageId NOT LIKE @PackageId";
```

My next idea is loop through the list from my original query and use these values within the select statement, something like this:

```
List<Package> listPackages = PackageList(packageId);
string listItem = "";
for (var i = 0; i < listPackages.Count(); i++)
{
    listItem = "NOT LIKE " + listPackages.ToString() + " AND ";
}

string showProdQuery = 
    @"SELECT DISTINCT ProdName FROM Products P " +
    "INNER JOIN Products_Suppliers S ON P.ProductId = S.ProductId " +
    "INNER JOIN Packages_Products_Suppliers O ON S.ProductSupplierId = O.ProductSupplierId " +
    "INNER JOIN Packages G ON G.PackageId = O.PackageId " +
    "WHERE P.ProdName " +
    listItem +
    "G.PackageId NOT LIKE @PackageId";
```

I don't know if this is an appropriate approach or if I am missing something really simple. I'd love any advice on how I can make this work.

Here is the updated query I managed to make work. Thank you for the advice everyone.

```
string showProdQuery = 
    @"SELECT DISTINCT ProdName FROM Products P " +
    "INNER JOIN Products_Suppliers S ON P.ProductId = S.ProductId " +
    "INNER JOIN Packages_Products_Suppliers D ON S.ProductSupplierId = D.ProductSupplierId " +
    "WHERE P.ProductId = S.ProductId AND S.ProductSupplierId = D.ProductSupplierId AND P.ProductId " +
    "NOT IN (SELECT ProductId FROM Products_Suppliers S " +
    "INNER JOIN Packages_Products_Suppliers D ON S.ProductSupplierId = D.ProductSupplierId " +
    "AND D.PackageId = @PackageId)";
```

Comment: Can you show us your attempt to use `NOT IN`? Basically doing something like `SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Table1Column NOT IN (Select Table2Column FROM Table2)`?

Comment: Can't you just do a left join somewhere or write a better query.  It seems like all the information you need is in the database.

Comment: Also if @PackageId is a single value why not use not equal instead of not like?

Comment: Since `listPackages` is a `List<Package>`, then `listPackages.ToString()` will be something like `"System.Collections.Generic.List'1[Namespace.Package]"`. Also, if there's more than one item in the list, your `listItem` string will only contain the last one. Should you be concatenating it instead?

Comment: Thank you everyone for the comments. This query took a lot of trial and error but JimmyShoe was right about being able to do this with the info in the database. I will post an update with the working query.